# Show category ID on custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, categories, taxonomy

I have a clients who's using the [WPCasa theme](https://wpcasa.com/).

The theme has a Custom Post Type named `properties` and has categories on it (`for rent`, `for sale`, etc.).

My client wants to show the category of the property on it's title (i.e. "For rent - House on Miami Beach"). However, I'm not being able to get it. I'm looking codes and trying all of them, but there's no result.

I don't know if it's the codes or I'm not placing it on the right place (I'm doin' it on `functions.php`).

If anyone can help me, I would be really thankful.

The code I'm trying is this:

```
<?
php $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'custom taxonomy name' ); 
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    echo  $term->name 
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A little clarification:
>
> - **taxonomy** is a container of terms
> - **term** is the classification of an object (post, project, property)
>
> "Post Categories" is a taxonomy. The Categories inside are
>   terms.

**UPDATE**

For single posts:

Use the code you posted, in the `single.php` file (or the template file for this custom post type), but you should change '`custom taxonomy name`' to the correct taxonomy slug.

You can easily get the slug, by going in the backend, then go in the taxonomy page as you normally would to add more terms.
In the url you'll see the slug of the taxonomy after `&taxonomy=`

eg.

```
http://www.example.com/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=the_taxonomy_nameis_here&post_type=properties
```

Make sure that it's after the beginning of the loop `if(have_posts()): while(have_posts()) : the_post()`

For term pages:

Use this code in the taxonomy page (eg. `category.php`, `archive.php` or what your template uses for this taxonomy)

```
global $wp_query;
$term = $wp_query->queried_object;
echo '<h1>'.$term->name.'</h1>';
```

Comment: I'm going to try this. I've found a way thorugh a plugin that my clients has installed, but every time he publish hast to set the category.
Do I have to put it on function.php, do I?

Comment: No, add it to the taxonomy category template file.
Depending on your template structure, this file could be different.
The standard category template file is `category.php`, but sometimes `archive.php` is used instead.
However, templates that have custom post types (property in your case), might also have custom category templates.
The file could be named `yourtempltate/taxonomy-theslugofthattax.php`

Comment: Ok, I'd try doing this.
Really apreciate

Comment: One more thing.
If I want to give some stylea to the tag, it's possible?
It's my first time with taxonomies and cpt and I'm barely lost...

Comment: OK, I've tried and doesn't work =/

Comment: @franfernandz can you please post in the OP the name of the file you edited and the full page code.

Comment: I updated my answer, because I got confused if you need it in the single property or in the category page. So now you have both methods.

Comment: I'm going to try on the simple.php.
Anyway, my client install a plugin for his theme (at the same time that I was testing this code =/), but I'm going to need it to another design.
If it works, I'll colse the question.

Thank you so much for your help =)